# Como excluir métodos gerados automaticamente pelo Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

Estou fazendo um GUI utilizando o `JFrame` gerado de forma automática pelo  Netbeans e tiveram vezes que cliquei duas vezes em um `JButton` sem querer e ele gerou automaticamente um código de `ActionEvent` que não pode ser editado.

Como não queria esses métodos que não iria utilizar, abri o código por um outro editor (Sublime) e os retirei por completo, tanto os métodos como as chamadas dele no `private void initComponents()`.

Depois de exclui-los pelo sublime eles deixaram de existir quando abri no Netbeans e o código rodou normalmente.

O problema é que, sempre depois que altero alguma coisa pelo NetBeans, aqueles métodos misteriosamente voltavam a serem chamados no `private void initComponents()`. Com isso o, para poder compilar sem erros, tenho que ficar abrindo novamente o Sublime e retira-los.

Ex: Código que eu excluo, mas que volta misteriosamente

<kbd>[image: Código que surge misteriosamente depois que excluo]</kbd>

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faça o seguinte:

1. Selecione o `JButton`(clique simples);
2. vai nas `Propriedades`(barra lateral direita inferior), e clique em `eventos`;
3. Clique no botão <kbd>...</kbd> ao lado do evento que está sendo criado(veja na foto um exemplo de como deverá estar):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4. Na janela que abrir, selecione o método action do botão e clique em <kbd>Remover</kbd> e depois em <kbd>ok</kbd>:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

5. Veja no código, o método foi removido lá tambem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funcionou!

Obrigada =]